# Detectar "Enters" con RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Mi problema es que tengo el siguiente `String` y quiero convertirlo a un array, siendo que cada palabra separada por un "enter' del string, sea un elemento del array.

`String`

```
"Uno
Dos
Tres"
```

`Array`

```
["Uno", "Dos", "tres"]
```

Comment: Hola, te sirvio la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = texto.split("\n");
```

Donde split es la función que se va a encargar de dividir la cadena, esta función recibe como parámetro el separador a tener en cuenta para dividir la cadena, "\n" es el enter

Comment: Hola podrías decirme si te sirvio la respuesta